# How can I bump major version to v2 without duplicating code of sub-packages and get latest version by default?

Tags: git, go, github, versioning, go-modules

I'm having trouble bumping major version, from `v1.x.x` to `v2.0.0`.

I created a new git tag, `v2.0.0` and a new sub-folder, `/v2/`, put `go.mod` file in it and changed the module name accordingly.

My module contains several sub-packages and now I cannot import them - even those which no changes were made to them.

For example, I cannot import `/v2/mypkg/` - I get `module found but does not contain package` error. As mentioned, this folder contains `go.mod` file only.
I couldn't figure out - in case no changes were made to `mypkg` - if I'm expected to make another copy (?!) of the package, so that the same code will exist both in `mypkg/` and `v2/mypkg/`.

I tried to look for examples online in common Go repositories, and it seems like:

- All repos that use go-mod are below v2
- Repos above v2 are not 100% compatible with go-mod

I can work around it by importing my package with `+incompatible`, and then creating a git tag is enough (without creating `/v2`). But then, if I import the package without strictly require `v2.0.0`, I get the latest `v1.x.x` by default, which is not really the latest which is problematic for me.

What can I do?

Comment: You don't have to copy anything. Just move all packages to the v2 directory and update the imports.

Comment: As for the "default" package: there is no such thing. You are creating a completely new module. Its name just happens to have a common prefix with the old name.

Comment: That means that if someone starts a new project and needs to import my module, they need to explicitly import `v2` to get the latest version, and otherwise they get the latest of `v1`. IMHO this is fairly weird

Comment: You don't need the `/v2` subdirectory in the actual module, it's only a name to indicate a different import path. It's a workaround for users that for some reason can't use modules, or you can't tag or branch versions in the vcs. For example, the [github.com/hashicorp/hcl/v2](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/hashicorp/hcl/v2?tab=doc) package has no v2 directory in the [repo](https://github.com/hashicorp/hcl)

Answer (score 0):

When you update the version to `v2`, you also need to update the `import` statements that refer to that version to use the `/v2` suffix on the module path.

Without that suffix, the imports refer to the packages in the original v1 module. (That may be useful if you are intentionally providing a compatibility shim between the two major versions.)

See [Developing a major version update](https://golang.org/doc/modules/major-version) for more detail..